# Extend mnist database

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I wonder how can I extend mnist database to recognize digits and only few characters like A,B. I use this tutorial for [mnist](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), how can I add to this database charater A and B ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do three things:

1. Add additional images of the letters A and B to the dataset (training, validation and test), with labels 11 and 12. The easiest way to extend the dataset might be with a subset of the EMNIST dataset https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/emnist-dataset
2. Change the number of outputs on the logit layer to 12 to accomodate the new characters (or 13 if you want a "none of the above" output because you intend to train on sybols you don't need recognised explicitly)

   logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=12)
3. Retrain the network from scratch since its weights in other layers were only generated with numbers in mind and would likely otherwise struggle to differentiate between 8 and B. You might get away with transfer learning from a previously trained network however and it might be interesting to try.

Comment: You would need to import the EMNIST dataset (as an array, a pandas datatable or as batches as you prefer) and combine the train, validate and test data if it comes presplit. Then sort the entries by label, remove all the entries corresponding to letters you do not wish to recognise. After this reshuffle the resulting dataset and divide into train, validate and test sets.

Comment: You'll likely need to write your own script for that, filtering out indices of the data array where the indices of the labels array don't have labels that are characters you want. Using the CSV file from Kaggle should make this doable.